# Solving a PDE for determining a metric

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

A friend is studying some Finsler metrics and she has come upon the following partial differential equation:

$$\begin{cases}
y^i\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial x^i}=0\\
y^i\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial y^i}=1\\
\end{cases},$$
where $b:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R},\ x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)\in\mathbb{R}^n, \ y=(y^1,\dots,y^n)\in\mathbb{R}^n.$

I have managed to find a family of solutions:
$$b_k(x,y)=\sqrt{|y|^2-k(|x|^2|y|^2-\langle x,y\rangle^2)},\ k\in\mathbb{R}.$$
 but I don't see how to solve the equation in general.

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of characteristics for solving 1st-order PDEs?

Comment: I do not know hot to apply it for the case $x$, $y$ $n$-dimensional. Just to be sure, $y^i\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial y^i}$ means $\sum_{i=1}^n y^i\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial y^i}$.

Answer (score 1):

Change the $y$ variables to spherical coordinates $(r,\theta)=(r,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1})$. Then 
$$1=y^i\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial y^i}=r\frac{\partial b(x,r,\theta)}{\partial r}$$
Hence $b(x,r,\theta)=\log r+F(x,\theta)$. By the first PDE, $F$ must satisfy:
$$0=y^i\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial x^i}=y^i(\theta)\frac{\partial F(x,\theta)}{\partial x^i}$$ Thus it is of the form $F(x,\theta)=F(x^iv_i(\theta),\theta)$ where $v$ can be functions of $\theta$ which are orthogonal to $y(\theta)$: $y^i(\theta)v_i(\theta)=0$ for all $\theta$. For example when $n=2$ and $(y^1,y^2)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$:
$$b(x,y)=\log r+F(x^2\cos\theta-x^1\sin\theta,\theta)$$

As you can see, the above solution does not cover the solutions you have found. I believe the solutions you suggested do not satisfy the second PDE but rather:
$$y^i\frac{\partial b(x,y)}{\partial y^i}=b(x,y)$$